# how to move windows xampp website to Centos Apache?

Tags: apache-http-server, centos, xampp

I have configured website using php script on my local machine using xampp, Now I have to move it to centos apache web server.

I did: moved folder from HTDOCS to `cento> var > www > html`
But it says `Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.`
only `index.php` works

Comment: Websites aren't really able to just be copy/pasted between different types of servers unless the site is very simple. What research have you done and what have you tried? What sort of code is running on the site? What dependencies?

Comment: Site is running with PHP script with mysql database